# Kotlin - Copy clicked items of a ListView to clipboard

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

I have to copy clicked items of a ListView to clipboard manager using Kotlin.

I've tried

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val item = listView.selectedItem as String?
            myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", item)
            myClipboard?.primaryClip = myClip }
```

But it says:

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
> ```

For my ListView I used

```
var values = ArrayList<String>()
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_text_color, values)
listView?.adapter = adapter
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: Make sure listView is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

Instead of using a listView layout, I used the alertDialog.setAdapter(). 
Here's the code

```
     alertDialogList.setAdapter(adapter, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, which ->
            val item = adapter.getItem(which) //this is my code to copy clicked items on clipboard
            myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", item)
            myClipboard?.primaryClip = myClip
})
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe your `listview` is null. Use `listview?.setOnItemClickListener` instead

Comment: It doesn't gives the error anymore, but for some reason  is always null, even if I add items to adapter. The code inside .SetOnItemClickListener doesn't works (the code is right, doesn't works with a simple Toast to)

Comment: that is because your listview is null. where does your listview come from?

Comment: From a layout that I used to build a custom alertDialog

Comment: maybe you use listview directly. you can't do that. what you can do is store the inflated layout to a variable. and if you want to access the listview, call inflatedLayoutValName.listview

Comment: Same thing, doesn't gives errors, but code inside setOnItemClickListenere{} still not works, even if is a simple Toast.makeText()

Answer (score 0):

```
    val clipboardManager = holder.itemView.context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
    val clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("text", "your text value")
    clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData)
    Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "Text copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

that's all enjoy your coding...